# Getting index of subtree in Stanford's parse trees

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to get the index of a subtree in a parsed sentence so that I can remove it.  Here is my code:

```
{
    Queue<Tree> queue = new LinkedList<Tree>();
    queue.add(tree);
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        Tree current = queue.poll();
        if (current.label().toString().equals("CC")) {
            List<Tree> siblings = current.siblings(tree);

            String leaf = current.getChildrenAsList().get(0).label().toString();
            Tree rightNode = siblings.get(1);
            Tree leftNode = siblings.get(0);
            if (leaf.contains("and") &&
                    rightNode.label().toString().contains("S")) {
                int index = rightNode.index();
                System.out.println("index " + index);
                System.out.println("returning index: " + tree.getChild(index).label().toString());  // testing to make sure it's the right node
            }
        }
        List<Tree> children = current.getChildrenAsList();
        for (Tree child : children) {
            if (!child.isLeaf()) {
                queue.add(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried every iteration of objectIndexOf that I can think of:

```
int index = tree.objectIndexOf(rightNode);
int index = current.objectIndexOf(rightNode);
int index = rightNode.objectIndexOf(current);
int index = rightNode.objectIndexOf(tree);
```

but every time I get a -1.  My program is correctly hitting the conditionals so clearly the "s" node is in that tree as a sibling to "CC." But I can't get it to return an index so that I may remove it.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.